# Why I cant submit this array to PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, deserialization, submit

I have a table with data and checkboxes aside. When I click in checkboxes I am taking the id of the item of each selected and when submit I am receiving in PHP BUT now I changed my approach. Now, I want to submit the entire array to PHP however I don't receive it:

```
 <?php foreach ($arr_cases as $cases) : ?>
   <tr>                           
     <td>           
       <input type="checkbox" name="devices" value="<?php $dataa = serialize($cases); $encodedd = htmlentities($dataa); echo $encodedd; ?>">
     </td>
   </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

The way I am doing above, I can ONLY receive ONE array in PHP, so, tried naming the checkboxes from `devices` to `devices[]` but this time its printing blank(nothing).

I, of course, unserialize it in PHP.
**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an array-style name for the checkbox so you receive all of them in an array.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[]" value="<?php $dataa = serialize($cases); $encodedd = htmlentities($dataa); echo $encodedd; ?>">
```

Then `$_POST['devices']` will be an array of all the checked values. Each element of this array will be serialized, and you'll have to unserialize it.

```
if (!empty($_POST['devices'])) {
    $devices = array_map('unserialize', $_POST['devices']);
} else {
    $devices = [];
}
var_dump($devices);
```

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it doesn't work. Show your code.

Comment: now it works, I was definitely right what I said about you in the other post.